# How can I check, the number that scanner received is an integer certainly in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method that must get an integer as input. How can I check that it is a integer certainly. if input is a string so get number again.

```
public int getMobileNumber() {
    System.out.println("Enter Mobile Number: ");
    int mobileNumber = input.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Mobile Number Registered!");
    return mobileNumber;
}
```

Comment: [`hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()), `hasNextLong` are in the documentation.

Comment: *I have a method that must get an integer as input.* - why do you read `.nextLong()` then?

Comment: if it is a string how can i get input again?

Comment: @fh.kazemi see the Java documentation. Namely, have a look at [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hasNextInt` method and a while loop to get definitely an integer:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a number:");

while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.printf("Your input was \"%s\". Please enter a number:%n", sc.next());
}

int num = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(num);

sc.close();
```